# Calculating covariance of a 3-dim matrix using einsum

Tags: numpy

I've got an array of time series data of shape `(2466, 2498, 9`) (`(asset, date, feature)`).

I've got 9 features, on which I want to do PCA to reduce the dimensionality on this axis.

I'm struggling to calculate the covariance matrix, `Z = X.T @ X`.

I think I want to express this as an `einsum`, but I'm not sure how. I'm certainly interested in other methods as well, as the purpose of this is to learn `numpy`, rather than actually solve a problem.

**Edit**: This is my (apparently wrong) attempt so far:

```
np.einsum('ijk,ijl->ijkl',myData, myData)`
```

(This just hangs my system.)

**Edit 2**:

I've come to understand that I should be using `np.linalg.svd` for this problem.

Comment: It seems correct. The problem probably is `8 * 2466 * 2498 * 9 * 9 / 1024 ** 3 = 3.7` (3.7 Gb) so it start to swap memory which hangs system.

Comment: In a case like this it's a good idea to test it with small arrays - ones that won't take too long, use up too much memory, and more importantly, can be viewed. Even more so if your primary goal is learning `numpy`